Error `system.CallFiltered` when using pure proxy
I have custom parachain with pallet_proxy configured on it. I have created a pure proxy. But when I tried to add a second proxy to the anonymous account, I got the following error:
system.CallFiltered

It seems to be a pretty straightforward error. However, the runtime configuration doesn't filter any proxy transaction-related at all. In fact, I have even tried removing all the filters, but still fails. Am I missing something?

Can you reproduce this on Rococo?There it is easier to see for everyone what is going wrong. Faucet is here https://faucet.polkadot.io/

@OliverTale-Yazdi I tried to reproduce it in paseo and it worked, so something is wrong in my code, but still haven't figured out where the error is

Can I have your chain's repo link?

Indeed, my configuration for the pallet_proxy was incorrect; this piece of code was missing:
impl InstanceFilter<RuntimeCall> for ProxyType {
    // missing function
    fn is_superset(&self, o: &Self) -> bool {
        match (self, o) {
            (x, y) if x == y => true,
            (ProxyType::Any, _) => true,
        }
    }
}

As far as I could understand, when proxy-related actions are performed through a proxy, it has to be checked that such proxy is a superset type. For example, it wouldn't make sense to be able to create an Any proxy type from a less restrictive proxy (e.g. Staking). Hope that makes sense.
